# Global symbol "@list" requires explicit package name error

Tags: perl, syntax, scope, perl-data-structures

The ordinary and simple "newbie perl code does not work and writer has no idea why" question:

```
sub print_hash {
    our %hash;
    my @list = sort {$hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} keys %hash;            
    foreach my $name (@list) {
        printf "$name $hash{$name}";
    }   
}
```

error:

```
syntax error at ./freq line 27, near "my "
Global symbol "@list" requires explicit package name at ./freq line 27.
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at ./freq line 27.
```

I assume I somehow messed my scopes up. Adding `our %hash` to the sort eval did not help, at all (threw more errors), and outsourcing it to a sub did the same. This code is almost directly stolen from an hash sorting tutorial. I would really appreciate an explanation of how I went wrong!

Comment: You need an editor that does syntax highlighting :-)

Comment: @DaveCross It does (vim) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two mistakes:

```
our %hash; # a semicolon missing
my @list = sort {$hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b}} keys %hash; 
                                        ^ a curly bracket!
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon after `our %hash`.

Comment: Original does not, fixed, plus I missed a curly bracket, which was the real problem.

Comment: You have unbalanced curly braces in the `map` call.

Comment: @AndyLester: There isn't a `map` call!

Comment: Sorry, I meant `sort`.